# Querying on Multi-Select Picklist in Get Records in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select

After a whole lot of frustration, I found out it's not possible in the `Get Records` action in Flow to filter on a multi-select picklist, and you get an error: [the idea to make this actually possible](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjCYUAZ/new-flow-designer-includes-option-for-multiselect-picklist-in-get-records-cond).

Are there any good workarounds for doing this - seemingly very normal - query?

Answer (score 3):

After similar frustration, I've gotten this to work by using the new `Collection Filter` Element, which apparently supports `Contains` for multi-select picklists (even though the `Get` Element does not).

1. Query the records you need via the `Get` Element, filtering down the results as much as possible through non-multi-select picklist fields.
2. Filter the results as needed using `Collection Filter` Element, including any multi-select picklist fields using the `Contains` operator.
3. Continue on your merry way through the flow.

*edit: clarified in bullet point #2 that by Filter I meant use the `Collection Filter`